# Is it possible to get an ISO 4217 currency code from Angular or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, currency

is there any way to get the ISO 4217 currency code for a locale? I'm using Angular. They have a utility function `getLocaleCurrencyName()` to retrieve the name like `euro`, `US dollar` etc. but not the currency code like `EUR`, `USD` etc. Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked this https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Comment: The `CurrencyPipe` only formats a currency. In fact, you need to pass it the currency code.

Answer (score -3):

Try getLocalCurrencySymbol(): https://pr18487-aedf0aa.ngbuilds.io/api/common/getLocaleCurrencySymbol

Note that '$' is not a currency code, it is a currency symbol. USD, CAD, AUD are a few currency codes for currencies that have the symbol '$'.

Comment: I want to get the currency code, not the currency symbol.

Comment: Then you should update your question and not include '$' as an example of what you expect